# Can't link my HTML/CSS Register form to MySQL database

Tags: php, html, database, authentication, mysqli

This is my first time trying to link an register/login form to an database. I've done some research on how I should do it and kind of followed an tutorial via youtube but I can't make it work.

**This is my html code for the form**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-sclae =1.0">
        <title>Inregistreaza-te</title>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d811942799.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/register.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>Inregistreaza-te</h1>
        <form action="insert.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nume de utilizator" name="username" required>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nume" name="nume" required>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Parola" name="parola" required>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Reintrodu parola" required>
        </form>
        <div class="terms">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" required>
            <label for="checkbox">Sunt de acord cu termenii si conditiile.</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" value="Sumbit">Inregistrare</button>
        <div class="member">
            Ai deja un cont? <a href="./login.html">
                Conecteaza-te
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**This is my php code**

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$parola = $_POST['parola'];
$nume = $_POST['nume'];

if (!empty($username) || !empty($parola) || !empty(nume)) {
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbUsername = "root";
    $dbPassword = "";
    $dbname = "webdesign";

    $conn = new mysqli($host, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbname);

    if (mysqli_connect_error()){
        die('Connect Error('. mysqli_connect_errno().')'. mysqli_connect_error());
    } else {
        $SELECT = "SELECT username From utilizatori Where username = ? Limit 1";
        $INSERT = "INSERT Into utilizatori (username, parola, nume) values(?, ?, ?)";

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($SELECT);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($email);
        $stmt->store_result();
        $rnum = $stms->nume_rows;

        if ($rnum==0){
            $stmt->close();

            $stmt = $conn->prepare($INSERT);
            $stmt->bind_param("sss", $username, $parola, $nume);
            $stmt->execute();
            echo "Utilizator nou inregistrat cu succes!";
        } else {
            echo "Deja exista un utilizator cu aceasta adresa de mail!";
        }
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    }

} else {
    echo "Toate campurile trebuie completate";
    die();
}

?>
```

[Here is my database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vm3CC.png)

Sorry in advance for being newbie with my question and have a nice day!

I have checked my code on phpcodechecker.net, initially there was a typing problem, solved id, now I have no error in my code(hopefully).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: There is a typo here - if (!empty($username) || !empty($parola) || !empty(nume)) - It must be $nume.